# Add delivery destination by city and apply a special price each city

Tags: magento2, checkout, price, special-price, delivery

I'm working on Magento 2, at checkout, I want to add a drop-down list to select cities for delivery and apply a special price for each city, the total amount should be updated according to the shipping cost for each destination.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this extension: http://webshopapps.com/row/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

This extension will allow you to upload a csv file with different prices per cities, countries, zipcodes.

Regards,
Pablo

Comment: I just tested it, it works well but if the field city was on a drop-down list it should be better, to avoid any misspelling.

Comment: A dropdown where? at checkout? You can add your own provinces/states to Magento and it will show as dropdown. But not cities.